# How do I Stop the Browser from Closing in VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to login automatically to a website and do work there. I would like it to stay open without a using a stop command (the stop commands prevents from running other vba). How can I keep the browser open?

```
Function OzarkLogin()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome", "https://supplyline.oreillyauto.com/wps/portal/supplyline/"
bot.Get "/"
bot.FindElementById("userId").SendKeys DLookup("[User ID]", "Ozark Password")
bot.Wait 1000
bot.FindElementById("password").SendKeys DLookup("[Password]", "Ozark Password")
bot.FindElementByName("loginbutton").Click
bot.Window.Maximize
Stop
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `bot` as public variable outside your function, that way it will not get destroyed when you end the function/sub. Don't forget to quit the driver at some point.

Comment: Thank you for your straight-forward answer. I saw many complex & unworkable answers when I searched. It works perfectly.